# Create another comment section for WordPress

Tags: comments

I want to create another comment section for a post type. For example one for comments and one for reviews. is this possible?

Comment: There might be plugins available for the same. Please check once.

Comment: @Chittaranjan I didn't find the plugin. Can you tell me a plugin or source code url/name?